# Kentico Reset password control VALIDATIONFAIL

Tags: passwords, reset, kentico

We've just deployed Kentico 9 in web farm mode to our production environment. Some users are experiencing issue with the reset password control on the login page. After they click the link in the email they receive an error is logged as follows:

Reset password control VALIDATIONFAIL
Event ID 22778
Message: Request identifier hasn't been found.
Exception type: System.Exception
Event URL: /CMSModules/Membership/CMSPages/ResetPassword.aspx?hash=9f1312c4c6cbfd4aa92c4705ed929eb1b87c348965815fc17700080595e7734f&datetime=19082016154349&returnurl=%2fSpecial%2fLogin.aspx%3f.

I've checked that the Macro Salt is in the web.config and followed the instructions for setting up the web farm (machine keys, sticky sessions etc.).

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue turned out to be due to an error in the SQL script that we used to do a bulk import of users. The script was not adding a row to the user preferences table. That table contains the hash used for password reset.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem multiple times and the reasons is Macros. If you are using some in built Kentico control or custom.

1. Just go to **System->Macros and re-assign all the macros** from a user having Global Admin access level. This will make sure that your macros will not fail.
2. Sometime going to that field in the **form control** and removing the validation and re-applying the validation also solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to configure Machine keys unless you want to share authentication between multiple web sites. Make sure that the CMSHashStringSalt like:

Is same in all your environments. Once it is, go to **System -> Macros** and re-sign all macros just to be sure.